# Why does GLES20RecordingCanvas#setBitmap always throw UnsupportedOperationException?

Tags: android, canvas, android-animation

So I'm creating a custom view for which I have to frequently (60 FPS) and infinitely draw different bitmaps to achieve animation.

I can't use AnimationDrawable, this isn't a set loop of repeating Drawables.

I thought it'd be as easy as onDraw() event in a custom view, I'd call setBitmap() on the canvas argument. However, I get an UnsupportedOperationException. On a Canvas I make my own outside of the onDraw() event, setBitmap works fine.

I see that I'm using a hardware accelerated implementation of the Canvas (GLES20RecordingCanvas) implicitly for my custom view. The implementation of the setBitmap() method is simply to throw a UnsupportedOperationException().

Why?

Comment: Most people her can only speculate about the reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here at the [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/HardwareCanvas.java?source=cc):

```
@Override
public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

The developers simply didnt't implement this method (yet)

Note that `GLES20Canvas extends HardwareCanvas` and `GLES20RecordingCanvas extends GLES20Canvas`